# How to set animated icons to stop after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have the following code to be displayed following an event:

```
$("span[name|='ttimer'").html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x' aria-hidden='true'></i> ");
```

How would it be possible to let the spinning motion last for example 3 seconds then stop moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this, `animation-iteration-count`

```
div {
    animation-iteration-count:3;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

this way let you do not have to remove the classname

Comment: @Maleka  if you are using css3 animation, add this to your animation className like `.fa-spin`.

Comment: .fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;}

Comment: should i replace infinite with '2' or '2s' ?

Comment: Looks like you could use `animation-duration` rather than `iteration-count`  try: `.fa-spin.fa-refresh { animation-duration: 3s }`

Comment: @Maleka Yes you should change the `infinite` property  to a number

Comment: @Maleka  @freesomn-m said may solve your problem, remember change `infinite` property to 1 or just don't set this property.

Comment: Also, you're overriding `.fa-spin` through out your entire site. You may want to restrict it to just `#some-parent-element .fa-spin {...`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note your attribute selector is missing the closing `]`.

To do what you require you would need to remove the `fa-spin` class on the element. You can do that using `setTimeout()`, like this:

```
var $span = $("span[name|='ttimer']").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
setTimeout(function() {
  $span.find('.fa-spin').removeClass('fa-spin');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I noticed the coding before, but the code never bugged. So I thought the code is just scanning through the first part of the string search.

Comment: I tried your code, but it seems that the spinning keeps starting again and stopping.

Comment: That would depend on what event you're running the code under. Could you edit your question to show more of your HTML and JS logic.

Comment: I think the reason behind this issue is due to the fact that this is being called with the response of an ajax call, which in turn is depending on a timer...

Comment: That sounds like the issue. If you're using AJAX polling I'd suggest you find an alternative method, as it's bad practice. Use websockets to keep the UI in sync with the server instead

Answer (score 1):

The animation is caused by `fa-spin` - you can remove this with a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("span[name|='ttimer']>i.fa-spin").removeClass("fa-spin");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it seems that the spinning keeps starting again and stopping.